# Using shortcode in theme customization alias - Shopify Theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Old version of theme used in section `Product Short Description` a `shortcode` from product description that was write like this:

`Product > Description (Rich Text block):`

```
[short_description]
...
[/short_description]

[description]
...
[/description]
```

And it's pasted to specific section in theme correctly. And not displayed in `Description` section below.

In new version they replaced `shortcodes` by `alias`, so now it's require `metafileds` (ex. `{{ product.metafields.meta.product_excerpt }}`).

[image: Theme metafileds]

But in editor it's quite hard to edit content.

I tried to get the old `shortcode` by using something like:

```
{{ product.description.short_description }}
```

or

```
{{ product.description.value[short_description] }}
```

But there is no result for it. It is possible to use this kind of `shortcodes` in `alias`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this can be using in **template** this rules:

```
product.description | split: '[short_description]' | last | split: '[/short_description]' | first
```

Maybe will be useful for someone.